# Superponer elementos

Tags: css, css3

Tengo un mapa y por encima quiero tener un contenedor que en un futuro será un modal para contener un formulario. El problema es que este aparece debajo y yo quiero que salga encima, he estado haciendo pruebas con `position` `z-index` etc pero nada termina de salir. ¿Como se hace?

Mi cabez me dice que debo tener un contenedor general (Gimnasios-Contenedor) y que sea el contenedor padre y que dentro tenga mapa y modal con una posición relativa y además jugar con los `z-index`

```css
#Gimnasios-Contenedor {
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: absolute;
}

#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  z-index: 50;
}

#ModalContacto {
  height: 300px;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: orangered;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div id="Gimnasios-Contenedor">
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="ModalContacto"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Debes asignar **al padre o ancestro** un `position: relative` para que se **transforme en el referente** del **modal** al cual se le agrega un `position: absolute;`, para **poder situarlo en coordenadas referentes al contenedor padre** o un `position: fixed`, **sí lo que deseas es que se posicione con respecto al tamaño total de la ventana** y al **map**, te recomiendo colocarle un `position: relative;` para que el z-index funcione como quieres, ya que **z-index, solo funciona en elementos que se le asigne la propiedad position**, diferente al por defecto que es `static`.

```css
#Gimnasios-Contenedor {
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
}

#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  background-color: cyan;
}

#ModalContacto {
  height: 300px;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: orangered;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  z-index: 100;
  background: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<div id="Gimnasios-Contenedor">
  <div id="map">mapa</div>
  <div id="ModalContacto">modal</div>
</div>
```

Como recomendación final, **te recomiendo que no uses valores tan altos de z-index**, por lo general en la mayoria de desarrollo o páginas funciona asignar del 1 al 20. Y en elementos flotantes permanentes como los menu flotantes o modales tipo lightbox, es que se usan valores altos como 100 o 1000.

Espero te haya aclarado, si tienes otra duda, escribeme un comentario. Éxitos.

Answer (score 8):

Si lo que deseas es tener el `div#ModalContacto` por encima del `div#map` entonces debes colocarlo en posición absoluta y moverlo con coordenadas en la posición que desees tenerlo, cabe aclarar que el `div` padre debe estar en posición relativa.

```css
#Gimnasios-Contenedor {
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
}

#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 50;
  background: black;
}

#ModalContacto {
  height: 300px;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: orangered;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 100;
  background: chocolate;
}
```

```html
<div id="Gimnasios-Contenedor">
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="ModalContacto"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Al div `Gimnasios-Contenedor`(padre) puedes poner `position: relative;` y al div `ModalContacto`(hijo)  puedes poner `position:absolute` para que se situe arriba y con eso **z-index** ya estaria por demas(por eso lo elimine).

```css
#Gimnasios-Contenedor {
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  z-index: 50;
}

#ModalContacto {
  height: 300px;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: orangered;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="Gimnasios-Contenedor">
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="ModalContacto"></div>
</div>
```